# Function that changes singular French nouns into plurals doesn't work properly (regex)

Tags: python, regex

I am currently reading "Dive Into Python" and in Chapter 6 the author has defined a function using regex that changes singular English nouns to plural ones. 
Here it is:

```
def plural(noun):
        if re.search('[sxz]$', noun):
             return re.sub('$', 'es', noun) 
        elif re.search('[^aeioudgkprt]h$', noun):
            return re.sub('$', 'es', noun)
        elif re.search('[^aeiou]y$', noun):
            return re.sub('y$', 'ies', noun)
        else:
            return noun + 's'
```

I decided to write a function that changes singular French nouns to plural ones. This is what it looks like:

```
def plural(noun):
    if re.search('[sxz]$', noun):
        return re.sub('$', '', noun)
    elif re.search(r'''au$|al$|ail$|
                [^\bbijou\b| # exceptions
                \bcaillou\b|
                \bchou\b|
                \bgenou\b|
                \bhibou\b|
                \bjoujou\b|
                \bpou\b]''', noun, re.VERBOSE):
        return re.sub('au$|al$|ail$', 'aux', noun)
    elif re.search(r'''\bbijou\b|
                   \bcaillou\b|
                   \bchou\b|
                   \bgenou\b|
                   \bhibou\b|
                   \bjoujou\b|
                   \bpou\b''', noun, re.VERBOSE):
        return re.sub('ou$', 'oux', noun)
    elif re.search('eu$', noun):
        return re.sub('$', 'eux', noun)
    elif re.search('eau$', noun):
        return re.sub('$', 'eaux', noun)
    elif re.search('ou$', noun):
        return re.sub('ou$', 'ous', noun)
    else:
        return noun + 's'
```

It works for the most part, but! for some reason if a noun (for example: fleur) just needs to be added "s" (the "else" statement), it doesn't work... It just returns 'fleur', but should return 'fleurs'.
I run the code in the visualizer and this is where the problem is:

```
      elif re.search(r'''au$|al$|ail$|
            [^\bbijou\b|  
            \bcaillou\b|
            \bchou\b|
            \bgenou\b|
            \bhibou\b|
            \bjoujou\b|
            \bpou\b]''', noun, re.VERBOSE):
```

When I delete "[^\bbijou\b|
                \bcaillou\b|
                \bchou\b|
                \bgenou\b|
                \bhibou\b|
                \bjoujou\b|
                \bpou\b]" then the "else" part works. I just want to understand what exactly the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: Why not use an existing package like https://github.com/sblondon/pluralizefr

Comment: I didn't know about it, thank you for the link! But anyway I just wanted to try writing some code myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\bbijou\b
```

just means: Anything that `^` does not match either `\b` (backslash), `b` `i` `j` `o` or `u`

and therefor matches `f`leur.

Do you mean: `\bbijou\b` ?

Comment: Yes! Thank u so much! Just deleted the exceptions from that "elif" statement and just left them in the following "elif". It works now! Thanks!